# @Builder(toBuilder = true) on constructor: Error "has private access"

Tags: java, lombok

I have the following 2 parent-child classes..

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract class Data {

    @Getter
    private final String name;

    @Getter
    private final String source;

    @Getter
    private final String message;
}
```

And

```
public class EventData extends Data {

    @Getter
    private String errorCode;

    @Getter
    private String errorMessage;

    @Getter
    private String api;


    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public EventData(String eventName, String errorCode, String eventMessage, String api, String errorMessage) {
        super(eventName, EventSource.BARCLAYS_GIL_PLUGIN_A_REST_SERVICE, eventMessage);
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
        this.api = api;
    }

}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    [javac] /local/home/vishivan/workplace/xyx/src/ABC/src/com/LOL/mno/models/EventData.java:36: error: eventMessage has private access in Data
    [javac]     @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    [javac]     ^
    [javac] 1 error
```

So here are my constraints

i need a builder in EventData and i need a copyconstructor to create the EventData object as well.. I tried adding setter@ and it resulted in error as final variables cant have setter defined... how can i solve this?

Comment: If you remove `(toBuilder = true)` it seems works. Do you need it?

Comment: You can use delombok and see what is wrong in this type of situation

Answer (score 5):

You are using `toBuilder = true`, and you have constructor parameters whose names differ from the corresponding fields in your superclass. Thus, lombok does not know how to extract the field values from an instance when populating a builder in the `toBuilder()` method.

To solve this problem, you can either use exactly the same names as your constructor parameters (if the fields are accessible from your subclass, e.g. `protected`), or give lombok a hint in which way to retrieve the field value. The latter can be achieved using the `@Builder.ObtainVia` annotation:

```
public EventData(@Builder.ObtainVia(method = "getName") String eventName, String errorCode, @Builder.ObtainVia(method = "getMessage") String eventMessage, String api, String errorMessage) {
    super(eventName, EventSource.BARCLAYS_GIL_PLUGIN_A_REST_SERVICE, eventMessage);
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    this.api = api;
}
```

Comment: This is a very helpful comment however this defeats the purpose of using @Builder and Lombok. I have the exact same problem and all my field names (e.g. version) have the exact same name like in the super class yet they required ObtainVia.